# Wrong picture appears when sharing a k2 item on facebook

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

i am using k2 v 2.6.7 on joomla 2.5

every time i share my k2 article to my Facebook page , wrong picture appears !!!

my website is http://aleppoprestigious.com/ar

any suggestions ?!!

Comment: What link are you sharing? Where is the picture from on your site that shows?

Comment: any article !!! for example , i need to share this article to my facebook page .. http://aleppoprestigious.com/ar/index.php/2013-12-15-15-14-03/item/173-2014-02-22-09-32-18

Comment: when i do thate wrong picutre appears!! ... and whene i use like button in k2 , it appears in my profile without piciure at all !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well , thanks for comments , i found the solution in http://getk2.org/community

it was about new release 2.6.8 , so i update the k2 version and from  K2 parameters,choose the desired image size for Facebook and click save.

Note that Facebook is applying caching so you need to test with a new item after you make the changes.